# Using an uuid or guid as id in grails/hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, hibernate-mapping

I need to have GUID/UUID's as the id column of my rows.

This is to be able to create entries both online and offline, and of course not having these conflict on PK when merging. I know i could mitigate this, but i'd like to keep it simple, and there is legacy apps already using uuid/guids to define relationships). Data also needs to be synced both ways later. Rewriting existing applications is not an option.

When i try to use either GUID or UUID with grails i get an error 500. (using a GUID on h2 results in another error - detaling that DB does not support GUIDs, as expected).

I get this error when i try to save an 'WithUUID':

```
URI    /gtestUUID/withUUID/save
Class    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message    argument type mismatch
```

Entire Error 500:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C17qU.png

I've tried with mariadb 5.5 and 1.1.7 driver, this results in the same problem.

Grails 2.3.8. Windows 8.1 (x64). Netbeans 7.4

all default.

Example classes:

WithUUID.groovy:

```
package gtestuuid

class WithUUID {
    String name
    static constraints = {
    }
    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'uuid'
    }
}
```

WithUUIDController.groovy:

```
package gtestuuid

class WithUUIDController {
    def scaffold = WithUUID
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Link to relevant grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html)

(i'm not able to post links to more docs/posts due to my low rep)

Comment: I think you need to set the id as String or UUID (or anything you need)

Comment: Thanks! i never considered that option. Please submit as answer, and i'll mark it as correct

Comment: Done! (with another possibility)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the id as String or UUID (or anything you need).

Below, an example of my class User with another possibility:

```
import java.util.UUID

class User {

    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

    static mapping = {
        id generator:'assigned'
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend using this method over the other, the other one (generator:'uuid2') caused many problems, I can't retrieve any record by id

Answer (score 10):

Or you can specify UUID id field in your class without any initializing and set mapping like in this case

```
class Buyer {

    UUID id
    String name
    String phone
    String email

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        id generator : 'uuid2', type: 'pg-uuid' // pg-uuid because I use postgresql
    }

}
```

You can take out mapping in Config.groovy

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    id generator : 'uuid2', type: 'pg-uuid'
}
```

and your classes will contain only UUID id field without any redudant code

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in my Grails 3 domain class...

```
class MyClass {    
    static constraints = {
    }

    UUID id
    static mapping = {
        id generator: "UuidGenerator", length: 36, type: "uuid-char"

   }


}
```

Then here's what I have inside UuidGenerator.groovy

```
import org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator;
import  org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor

import java.security.SecureRandom;

/**
 * 
 */
class UuidGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
    Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) {

        UUID.randomUUID()
    }
}
```

For grails 2.x.x my UuidGenerator.groovy looks like this...

```
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.SessionImplementor
import org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator;
import org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor;


/**
 * 
 */
class UuidGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
    Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) {

        return UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    }
}
```

And my domain class looks like this...

```
class MyClass {    
    static constraints = {

    }

     String id 
    static mapping = {
        id generator: "com.novadge.UuidGenerator", length:36
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the id as a String and generator type "uuid" you get uuid behavior for your domain in Grails 3 with little effort.

```
class State  {
    String id
    String state 

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'uuid'
    }
```