# Handling the uniqueidentifier type when connecting to MS SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am very new to grails, so please forgive me if this is a silly question.  I'm currently using grails 3.1.

When creating a domain object for an existing MS SQL Server 2014 table, I'm not sure how to handle the SQL Server "uniqueidentifier" data type.  When I start the app up, I get the following error:

> Could not determine type for: uniqueidentifier, at table: testtable, for >columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(id)]

Is there a way to define the uniqueidentifier type so that it is recognized?  From reading the MS documentation, I believe that it is effectively a char(26), but I'm not sure how to make it a recognized/supported type.

Comment: think this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736208/using-an-uuid-or-guid-as-id-in-grails-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about grails, but I think you are mistaken by the char(26). A unique identifier is a guid https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

In .NET there is an exact representation of that type with that name (System. Guid). I don't if that is true for grails.

Hope that helps.